# Scala remove string between two markers with regex

Tags: regex, scala

I am expecting to remove lines b/w "& Hello Buddy" and "&endmarker&" inclusive. I used replaceAll like shown below and doesn't work any help pls...

```
val s1 =
  """
    |& Hello Buddy
    |------------------------------
    |Hello;
    |GO
    |My
    |use &endmarker&
    |   GO
    |World
    |go
    |, I am Naga
    |+++++++++++++++++++++++++
    |GOTO School
    |GO Heaven
  """


val rg =s1.replaceAll("(?m)&(.*)&endmarker&" ," ")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest

```
val rg =s1.stripMargin('|').replaceAll("(?s)& Hello Buddy(.*?)&endmarker&" ," ").trim()
```

Output:

```
GO
World
go
, I am Naga
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
GOTO School
GO Heaven
```

See the [Scala demo](http://ideone.com/VgV8hr)

The `.stripMargin('|')` will get rid of the indentation.

**Pattern details**

- `(?s)` - a DOTALL modifier, `.` matches any chars including line break chars
- `& Hello Buddy` - a literal string
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars as few as possible up to the first occurrence of...
- `&endmarker&`  -  a literal string.

If you have a big file to process, the pattern should be re-written for better performance as

```
"(?s)& Hello Buddy[^&]*(?:&(?!endmarker&)[^&]*)*&endmarker&"
```

where `.*?` lazy dot is replaced with an unroll-the-loop pattern `[^&]*(?:&(?!endmarker&)[^&]*)*` that matches

- `[^&]*` - 0+ chars other than `&`
- `(?:&(?!endmarker&)[^&]*)*` - zero or more occurrences of:

  - `&(?!endmarker&)` - a `&` not followed with `endmarker&`
  - `[^&]*`  - 0+ chars other than `&`